# windows file permission confusion

Tags: php, windows, cmd, permissions, chmod

I have a php script that will change the file permissions. i would like to (lock) that file by making all the permission to zero but i'm getting some numbers that i don't understand

```
    echo fileperms("file.txt");
    echo '<br>';
    chmod("file.txt",0000);
    clearstatcache();
    echo fileperms("file.txt");
```

the output of the code is something like

33206

33060

i have tried to test it after executing those lines i found out that now the file is read-only file.

is there way to make the file not writable, readable and executable ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the [PHP File Lock Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php).

```
bool flock ( resource $handle , int $operation [, int &$wouldblock ] )
```

And use these options for `$operation`:

- LOCK_SH to acquire a shared lock (reader).
- LOCK_EX to acquire an exclusive lock (writer).
- LOCK_UN to release a lock (shared or exclusive).

Comment: i have tried this, but still after executing i'm able to read and write from/to the file

Comment: @alkoofi Do you want the file to _remain locked_ after the PHP is done running?